# return value from java controller

Tags: javascript, java, angular, playframework, controller

I'm new with java controllers. I'm working on Play framework and I'm trying to return an ArrayList from the controller, and it gives errors.
What is the right way to do so? My code is right below.

Another question, I would like to write the simplest page with html and javascript angular functionality which call the Play framework controller. Is there a simple platform like Play framework but for the front side?

this method:

```
public Result getComments(int postId) {        
    ArrayList<Comment> comments = this.commentsDic.getComments(postId);        
    return ok(comments);
}
```

gives the following error:

```
no suitable method found for ok(java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment>)
method play.mvc.Results.ok(play.twirl.api.Content) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment> cannot be converted to play.twirl.api.Content)
method play.mvc.Results.ok(java.lang.String) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment> cannot be converted to java.lang.String)
method play.mvc.Results.ok(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment> cannot be converted to com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)
method play.mvc.Results.ok(byte[]) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment> cannot be converted to byte[])
method play.mvc.Results.ok(java.io.InputStream) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment> cannot be converted to java.io.InputStream)
method play.mvc.Results.ok(java.io.File) is not applicable
  (argument mismatch; java.util.ArrayList<models.Comment> cannot be converted to java.io.File)
```

and this way:

```
    public ArrayList<Comment> getComments(int postId) {        
    ArrayList<Comment> comments = this.commentsDic.getComments(postId);        
    return comments;
}
```

gives this error:

```
Cannot use a method returning java.util.ArrayList[models.Comment] as a Handler for requests
```

pointing to the routes file on the marked line:

```
# Routes
# This file defines all application routes (Higher priority routes first)
# ~~~~

# An example controller showing a sample home page
GET     /                           controllers.HomeController.index
# An example controller showing how to use dependency injection
GET     /count                      controllers.CountController.count
# An example controller showing how to write asynchronous code
GET     /message                    controllers.AsyncController.message

****************the error points on this line:************
GET     /comments                            
controllers.CommentsController.getComments(postId: Integer)

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file                       
controllers.Assets.versioned(path="/public", file: Asset)
```

The full controller code:

```
package controllers;

import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

import services.CommentsDictionary;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import models.Comment;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Singleton;

import java.util.List;


@Singleton
public class CommentsController extends Controller {

private final CommentsDictionary commentsDic;

@Inject
public CommentsController() {
   this.commentsDic = new CommentsDictionary();
}


public List<Comment> getComments(int postId) {        
    List<Comment> comments = this.commentsDic.getComments(postId);        
    return comments;
}

}
```

Comment: Can you share result class?

Comment: What do you mean by result class?

Comment: In you first method you have mention return type Result .

Comment: Can you share full code?

Comment: Result is default object of java. It's not my object. Result is used to wrap simple objects (as string) as answer from java controllers. This is what I know about it.

Comment: In last method can you try with List instead of ArrayList.

Comment: Can you post your full code? Definitely will help youbto fix your issue.

Comment: I have updated the question. Thank you so much for your time.

Comment: After doing list insteadof arraylist your issue got resolved or not?

Comment: No. Same error like the last one.

Comment: Have you debug and check the value of this.commentsDic.getComments(postId)?

Comment: This is a compilation problem. As far as I understand, the controller has to return a object wrapped with the Result object, but the Result object can have only primitive objects, and list or array list is not

Comment: why don't you change your list object in primitive?

Comment: Because list is not a primitive type by default.

Comment: Every route needs to return a HTTP response. This isn't a normal Java function. Start by wrapping it in an `Ok` or something, not just returning a plain value.

Comment: You might need to define a toString method or something like that before it allows you to return this stuff in an HTTP response. I use Scala Play daily, not Java though so specifics may be a little different.

Answer (score 2):

Which content type of HTTP response do you want?

If you want Json simply return

```
ok(play.libs.Json.toJson(comments));
```

If you want show page render template like this:

```
ok(views.html.yourTemplate.render(comments));
```

Some tips for further reading:

https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/JavaActions#Results
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.8/api/java/play/mvc/Results.html